# Creating custom dropdown, why is width of child element wider than its parent?

Tags: css

I am trying to build a custom dropdown component for React. Unfortunately, my child list's width, which I have set to 100%, is showing up as wider than its parent element.

The DOM:

```
<div className="dd-wrapper" id={this.state.wrapperID}>
    <div className="dd-header" id={this.state.headerID} onClick={() => this.toggleList()}>
        <div className="dd-header-title"></div>
    </div>
    <ul className="dd-list hidden" id={this.state.listID}>
        <li className="dd-list-item">Test</li>
        <li className="dd-list-item">Test2</li>
        <li className="dd-list-item">Test3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the `toggleList` function removes the `hidden` class from the list, and adds a border property class `dd-border` to the wrapper, which is also not behaving properly (the border is wrapping only the header).

It is being called in the parent element like this (I am using Bootstrap grid):

```
<div className="col-md-3">
    <label> Dropdown
        <Dropdown id="test-dd"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant css:

```
.dd-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.dd-header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #E2E8F2;
  background-image: url("assets/images/down-chevron.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
}

.dd-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.dd-list li {
  height: 40px;
}

.dd-border {
  border: 1px solid #3d70b2;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

How can I get the width to match its parent without doing it manually (to ensure it will work for any size of dropdown? And, secondarily, does anyone know a good trick for getting the border to cover the child as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A quick note:** This is a CSS question so your React logic is just acting as a hurdle for anyone willing to answer. I've extracted the important parts based on your description into a working snippet below without React. I would recommend pulling out anything not crucial to the context of your questions to encourage more prompt answers.

> How can I get the width to match its parent without doing it manually (to ensure it will work for any size of dropdown?

I think the main thing you are looking for is `position: relative` on the parent. Because absolutely positioned elements size and position themselves against the first "positioned" ancestor. As a result, you can then combine this with `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `width` and/or `height` values (and probably `box-sizing: border-box;`)

> ...does anyone know a good trick for getting the border to cover the child as well?

You can fake it by putting the dropdown right up against the bottom and toggling a class on a common parent to hide/show certain borders.

Here's the snippet to demonstrate:

```js
// The toggle logic in vanilla JS just to make the example work
// This, instead of toggling "hidden" on the list, toggles a "dd-closed" class on the wrapper
const wrapperEl = document.querySelector('.js-wrapper')
const headerEl = document.querySelector('.js-header')
if (wrapperEl && headerEl) {
  const ancestorLabel = headerEl.closest('label')
  const targetEl = ancestorLabel ? ancestorLabel : headerEl
  targetEl.addEventListener('click',
    () => wrapperEl.classList.toggle('dd-closed')
  )
}
```

```css
.dd-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.dd-header {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #E2E8F2;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
  border: 1px solid #3d70b2;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

.dd-header::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '\25B4';
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 1em;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.dd-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #3d70b2;
  margin-top: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dd-list li {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 1em;
}

.dd-list li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.dd-closed > .dd-header::before {
  content: '\25BE';
  float: right;
}
.dd-closed > .dd-header {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
.dd-closed > .dd-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Basically what React would render as your output HTML...plus any necessary changes -->
<label> Dropdown
  <div class="dd-wrapper dd-closed js-wrapper">
    <div class="dd-header js-header">
      <div class="dd-header-title"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="dd-list">
      <li class="dd-list-item">Test</li>
      <li class="dd-list-item">Test2</li>
      <li class="dd-list-item">Test3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</label>
<p>(Some other content for the dropdown to cover)</p>
<button>(I do nothing)</button>
```